# Adding worldmap shapefile in full extent over south american raster map

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile

I would like to add the Worldmap shapefile over the South-American precipitation raster. I used the code below

```
# Calling variables
Prec <- raster("C:/Users/DELL/OneDrive/Desktop/test1/wc2.1_10m_prec_01.tif")
S_USA <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/DELL/OneDrive/Documents", layer = "South_America")

# Cropping and masking
Prec_USA_c <- crop(Prec, S_USA)
Prec_USA_m <- crop(Prec_USA_c, S_USA)

# Plotting
plot(Prec_USA_m)
plot(S_USA, add = TRUE)
```

But, I found that the extent of world map shapefile is reduced to fit to that of raster. I have attached an image of what I am getting.

But this is not what I want. I want to plot the raster within the world_map shapefile, retaining shapefile's full extent. May I know how can I do that ?

Please help

source of raster    : https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html [precipitation, 10 m]

source of south America shapefile used for cropping raster: https://tapiquen-sig.jimdo.com/english-version/free-downloads/south-america/

source of of world shapefile (overlaying; I removed Antarctica from it before plotting on raster): https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
[admin 0]

[image]

Comment: @Elia, the solution of Elia works. However, I am not able to get the lat and long labels on the bounding box. I think that it may be due to the layers that I am using. I have added the links to the layers that I have used (raster, south-Americal shape file for cropping, and world shape file to overlay). Could you please check.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to provide some example data so it is easier to help you and your expected output. However, if you want your plot to have the spatial extent of the entire world, just plot the globe before the precipitation cropped within South America.

```
library(terra)
library(rworldmap)
Prec <- rast("path/to/your/raster.tif")
world <-  vect(getMap()) 

# Cropping and masking
Prec_USA_c <- crop(Prec, world[world$continent=="South America",],mask=T)

# Plotting
plot(ext(world),axes=F)
plot(Prec_USA_c,add = TRUE,legend=F,axes=F)
plot(world,add = TRUE,legend=F,axes=T)
```

[image]

Two things here:

1. due to the data used in this example, South America also includes the states of Central America.
2. to make the boundaries visible over the precipitation data, I've first plotted the empty extent of the globe, then the precipitation data, and on top of all layers, the  globe boundaries.

**EDIT**

I've re-run my code with the data you provided and could not reproduce your problem (Axis label). See the code below:

```
library(terra)

Prec <- rast("C:/es/wc2.1_10m_prec/wc2.1_10m_prec_01.tif")
world <-  vect("C:/es/input/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp") 
world <- world[world$CONTINENT!="Antarctica",]
SA <-  vect("C:/es/South_America/South_America.shp") 

# Cropping and masking
Prec_USA_c <- terra::crop(Prec,SA)

# Plotting
plot(ext(world),axes=F)
plot(Prec_USA_c,add = TRUE,legend=F,axes=F)
plot(world,add = TRUE,legend=F,axes=T)
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

And as you can see, the coordinates are perfectly visible outside the bounding box